# Подстановка Конвертера Валют на сайт

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, парсер

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста. Есть некий код, собирающий данные определенной страны в шапке на сайте:

```
<?php $today = date("d/m/Y"); $fp = fopen('cb.xml', 'w'); $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req='.$today); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); curl_exec($ch); fclose($fp); curl_close ($ch); ?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function () { jQuery.ajax({ type: "GET", async : false, url: "cb.xml", dataType: "xml", success: Kurs }); function Kurs (xml) { jQuery(xml).find("Valute").each(function(){ if(jQuery(this).attr('ID')=='R01235') { usd = jQuery(this).find("Value").text(); jQuery(".rub span").text(parseInt(jQuery('.usd span').text())*parseInt(usd)); } }); } });</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>

<div id="banner_g1">
<?php
$adres = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parts = parse_url($adres);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
$need_id = $query['id'];

include "php/dbc.php";
$dbcnx = @mysql_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8'", $dbcnx);
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
mysql_select_db($DB_NAME, $dbcnx);

$bg_head_pic = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM law_content WHERE id = $need_id");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($bg_head_pic)) {
    if ( $row['bg_head_pic']!= '' ) {
        echo '<img id="img_bb" alt="'.$row['logo_alt'].'" src="/images/'.$row['bg_head_pic'].'" />';
        echo '</div><div id="banner_g2"><div id="banner_g2t1">'.$row['main_head_string'].'</div><marquee><div class="lenta-rbk">{module 177}</div></marquee><div id="banner_g2b">';
        echo '<img alt="'.$row['logo_alt'].'" src="/images/'.$row['logo_pic'].'" />';
        echo '<div id="banner_g2t2"><p>СТОИМОСТЬ ГОТОВОЙ КОМПАНИИ:</p><ul><li class="usd">от <span>'.$row['cost'].'</span> <span class="new_head_curr">'.$row['currency'].'</span></li>';
        echo '<li class="rub">от <span>100</span> рублей (по курсу ЦБРФ)</li></ul><p><a href="/gotovie-kompanii-s-otkritim-schetom.html" target="">Компании со счетом</a></p></div></div>';
    }
}
mysql_close($dbcnx);
?>
</div>
```

Код был написал пару лет назад наспех и мы видим, что вначале парсится центробанк. Но в данном случае подставляется только Доллар!
За это отвечает кусок:

```
 if (jQuery(this).attr('ID')=='R01235') {
  usd = jQuery(this).find("Value").text();
  jQuery(".rub span").text(parseInt(jQuery('.usd span').text())*parseInt(usd));
}
```

Также есть и случаи с ЕВРО, выглядит уже так:

```
if (jQuery(this).attr('ID')=='R01239') {
    eur = jQuery(this).find("Value").text();
    jQuery(".rub span").text(parseInt(jQuery('.eur span').text())*parseInt(eur));
}
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы вариант EUR или USD использовался сам, в пределах этого кода?
PS: Это зависит от $row['currency'], которая имеет значения либо "eur" либо "usd".

**Заранее спасибо !**

Comment: треш какой то а не код.

Comment: На данный момент я четко представляю, что здесь от jQuery можно вообще отказаться ! Т.к.:
- парсим при помощи php (изначально);
- перемножаем на курс на сайте уже поверх загрузки при помощи jQuery (вынужденная мера);
- в данном случае собрали общий модуль, который позволяет не использовать JS, но как здесь обойтись чистым PHP я пока не понял... =\

Comment: ну у вас же выводятся строки `echo <li class="rub">от <span>100</span> рублей`, которые заменяются потом на jquery, вот и впишите туда вместо `100` проверку валюты и пересчет по курсу. Вернее в цикле сначала посчитайте в рубли, а потом подставьте вместо 100 нужное значение. Для этого нужно значения курса извлечь из полученного через `сurl` xml-файла. Вообще подход плохой. Лучше в `cron` добавьте задачу которая **раз в сутки** будет получать текущий курс валют и запихивать в БД c текущей датой, а потом текущую цену можете прямо в запросе считать.

Comment: "Лучше в cron добавьте задачу которая раз в сутки будет получать текущий курс валют и запихивать в БД c текущей датой, а потом текущую цену можете прямо в запросе считать" (с)
Тоже подумал об этом, т.к .уже модуль претерпевает улучшения в нормальную сторону...

Comment: тут основной вопрос в том, что курс валют сам по себе меняется не чаще раза в день, поэтому извлекать его при каждом посещении страницы смысла нет никакого. Во-вторых, если показывается стоимость по текущему курсу, то, возможно, полезно хранить историю изменений курса, во избежание спорных ситуаций с клиентами. Да и пересчитывать цену в JS смысла нет никакого, надо изначально выводить нужное значение. Можно и без cron обойтись,просто при первом посещении проверять есть ли курс в базе, если нет, то запрашивать и запихивать в базу, а потом с ним считать.

Comment: "тут основной вопрос в том, что курс валют сам по себе меняется не чаще раза в день" (с) Уже давно вкурсе, конечно... "Да и пересчитывать цену в JS смысла нет никакого" (с) безусловно, т.к. это был вынужденный костыль, когда цены не выводились конкретно отдельными данными... "Можно и без cron обойтись..." (с) угу )

Comment: Сейчас код выглядит вот так - http://joxi.ru/Dr84o8Jh4npk3r
В таблицу "law_all_currency" раз в сутки парсится курс бакса и евро...